# Handling spaces in Uri path

Tags: c#, wpf, uri

I have a path to an image coming from DB in the form: Pictures/image_1.jpg in WPF and
am using a converter.

and I'm trying to create a Uri where my current directory is;
G:\Projects - Visual Studio\Stamps\Stamps\bin\debug

```
public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            if (targetType == typeof(ImageSource))
            {
                if (value is string)
                {
                    string str = value.ToString();
                    Uri uri = null;

                    if (str == "None")
                    {
                        uri = new Uri(str, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
                        return new BitmapImage(new Uri("Pictures/NoImage.jpg", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        // This one does not work because my path has spaces
                        uri = new Uri(str, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
                        // The following works because it has no spaces in path name
                        //uri = new Uri("Z:/Zipped/" + str);
                        BitmapImage bmi = new BitmapImage();
                        bmi.BeginInit();
                        bmi.UriSource = uri;
                        bmi.EndInit();
                        return bmi;
                    }
                }
                else if (value is Uri)
                {
                    Uri uri = (Uri)value;
                    return new BitmapImage(uri);
                }
            }
            return value;
        }
```

then in xmal file I have;

```
<Window.Resources>
    <con:ImageToSourceConverter x:Key="ImageSourceConverter"/>
</Window.Resources>

<DataGrid Name="dgUsers" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
          IsReadOnly="True"
          CanUserSortColumns="False"
          VerticalGridLinesBrush="Transparent"
          ItemsSource="{Binding}">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Scott #" Binding="{Binding [ScottNumber]}" />
        <DataGridTemplateColumn>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Image Width="42" Margin="0 5px" Source="{Binding Path=[ImagePath], Converter={StaticResource ImageSourceConverter}}"></Image>
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Description" Binding="{Binding [Description]}" />
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

The path to the file is not found and no image is displayed when there are spaces in the path and when there are no spaces it works fine.
So my question is now do I handle spaces in the path when creating  Uri?

I've also tried creating an absolute Uri and replacing spaces with "%20" and "+" and both caused an exception.

Answer (score 0):

[This article solved my problem](https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2019/Aug/20/UriAbsoluteUri-and-UrlEncoding-of-Local-File-Urls)

```
   var baseUri = Environment.CurrentDirectory;
    uri = new Uri($"file:///{baseUri}" + "/" + str, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
```

By adding the file:/// to the Uri it resolved successfully!