# Using ResourceDictionary results in Resource 'xxx' not found

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, wpf-style

I'm currently trying to organize my UI Xaml by splitting it into multiple files whenever it makes sense.

Because of that I'm exporting my TitleBar Styles into an extra file (`\UI\Styles\TitleBarButtonStyles.xaml`):

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">

<Style x:Key="TitleBarButton" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0,0,0,0" />
    <Setter Property="Height" Value="18" />
    <Setter Property="Width" Value="18" />
    <Setter Property="WindowChrome.IsHitTestVisibleInChrome" Value="True" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                <Border Width="{TemplateBinding Width}" Height="{TemplateBinding Height}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" CornerRadius="10">
                    <TextBlock Text="{TemplateBinding Content}" FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets" FontSize="10" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" RenderOptions.ClearTypeHint="Auto" TextOptions.TextRenderingMode="Aliased" TextOptions.TextFormattingMode="Display" />
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>

<!--Minimize-->
<Style x:Key="MinimizeButton" TargetType="{x:Type Button}" BasedOn="{StaticResource TitleBarButton}">
    <Setter Property="Content" Value="&#xE949;" />
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="LimeGreen" />
</Style>

<!--Maximize-->
<Style x:Key="MaximizeButton" TargetType="{x:Type Button}" BasedOn="{StaticResource TitleBarButton}">
    <Setter Property="Content" Value="&#xE739;" />
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Orange" />
</Style>

<!--Restore-->
<Style x:Key="RestoreButton" TargetType="{x:Type Button}" BasedOn="{StaticResource TitleBarButton}">
    <Setter Property="Content" Value="&#xE923;" />
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Orange" />
    <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
</Style>

<!--Close-->
<Style x:Key="CloseButton" TargetType="{x:Type Button}" BasedOn="{StaticResource TitleBarButton}">
    <Setter Property="Content" Value="&#xE106;" />
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Firebrick" />
</Style>
```

I then call it from the main file with:

```
 <Window.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="/UI/Styles/TitleBarButtonStyles.xaml" />
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Window.Resources>
```

And on the buttons with:

```
<Button Style="{StaticResource MinimizeButton}"
                    Grid.Column="2" 
                    Click="MinimizeBtn_OnClick" />

<Button x:Name="MaximizeBtn" Grid.Column="3" 
                    Style="{StaticResource MaximizeButton}" 
                    Click="MaximizeBtn_OnClick" />
<Button x:Name="RestoreBtn" Grid.Column="3" 
                    Style="{StaticResource RestoreButton}" 
                    Click="RestoreBtn_OnClick" />

<Button Style="{StaticResource CloseButton}" 
                    Grid.Column="4" 
                    Click="CloseBtn_OnClick" />
```

But on all buttons I get the error: `Ressource 'STYLE_X_KEY_NAME' is not found` (STYLE_X_KEY_NAME being the respective x:Key of the Style I wanted to apply)

**Edit**
Both files are in the same assembly.
I already tried the pack uri approach with:

```
<ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/VRChat Bases Manager;component/UI/Styles/TitleBarButtonStyles.xaml" />
```

It still shows the same error.

**Edit 2**
The folderstructure here is as follows:

Main file: `\UI\Windows\PrimaryWindow.xaml`
The Style File: `\UI\Styles\TitleBarButtonStyles.xaml`

**Edit 3**
For some reason my file `\UI\Styles\RoundDropDownStyle.xaml` that gets called in the same way works.

Here the file:

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
<Style x:Key="ComboboxTextBoxStyle" TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
                <Grid>
                    <Border CornerRadius="8, 0, 0, 8" BorderThickness="1,1,0,1" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" BorderBrush="#2A2A2A">
                        <ScrollViewer x:Name="PART_ContentHost" />
                    </Border>
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>

<Style x:Key="ComboboxButtonStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
                <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" x:Name="border" CornerRadius="0,8,8,0" BorderThickness="0,1,1,1" BorderBrush="#2A2A2A">
                    <ContentPresenter />
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>

<Style x:Key="ComboboxStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}">
    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
    <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
    <Setter Property="SelectedIndex" Value="0"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}">
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition />
                        <ColumnDefinition MaxWidth="18" />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <TextBox Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" Name="PART_EditableTextBox" Style="{StaticResource ComboboxTextBoxStyle}" Padding="5,0,0,0" Height="{TemplateBinding Height}" IsReadOnly="True" />
                    <ToggleButton Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" Grid.Column="1" Margin="0" Height="{TemplateBinding Height}" Style="{StaticResource ComboboxButtonStyle}" Focusable="False" IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsDropDownOpen, Mode=TwoWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" ClickMode="Press">
                        <Path Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Data="M 0 0 L 4 4 L 8 0 Z" Fill="DodgerBlue" />
                    </ToggleButton>
                    <ContentPresenter Grid.Column="0" Name="ContentSite" Content="{TemplateBinding SelectionBoxItem}" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding SelectionBoxItemTemplate}" ContentTemplateSelector="{TemplateBinding ItemTemplateSelector}" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="5,0,0,0" />
                    <Popup Grid.Column="0" Name="Popup" Placement="Bottom" IsOpen="{TemplateBinding IsDropDownOpen}" AllowsTransparency="True" Focusable="False" PopupAnimation="Slide">
                        <Grid Name="DropDown" SnapsToDevicePixels="True" MinWidth="{TemplateBinding ActualWidth}" MaxHeight="{TemplateBinding MaxDropDownHeight}">
                            <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" x:Name="DropDownBorder" BorderThickness="1" CornerRadius="5" BorderBrush="#2A2A2A" />
                            <ScrollViewer Margin="4,6,4,6" SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
                                <StackPanel IsItemsHost="True" KeyboardNavigation.DirectionalNavigation="Contained" />
                            </ScrollViewer>
                        </Grid>
                    </Popup>
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Comment: Can you show your folder structure? Where is your "main" file and where are the styles defined in relation to that?

Comment: Added the path of both files @ewerspej

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay I found the problem:
It was the build action property on the file.
It was set to `AdditionalFiles`. The file that was working had it set to `Page`. Once I changed that it worked like a charm.

Apparently it's a weird behaviour by Visual Studio 2022?
When you create a file by `Right Click -> Add... -> New Item... -> Resource Dictionary (WPF)` it works fine.
If you go `Right Click -> Add.. -> New From Template... -> Resource Dictionary` it has the build action set to `AdditionalFiles` which doesn't work.

**Edit**
I think the `New from Template...` is actually a feature added by ReSharper.

Comment: Yes, "New from Template" is a ReSharper context menu add in.

Answer (score 1):

Your Path should be,

```
<ResourceDictionary x:Name="TitleBarButtonStyles" Source="../Styles/TitleBarButtonStyles.xaml" />
```

As for your **pack uri approach**, you have spaces in URI. Consider [Handling spaces in Uri path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66302166/handling-spaces-in-uri-path)

Comment: I already tried it with `.../` instead of `/UI/`. I also gave it a name already, but I have no Idea how to call a specific Style of the Dictionary then aside from the fact, that it still doesn't detect it.

Comment: Please mind that it must be ```../``` (two dots, not three). Can you check from within the code behind if ```Application.Current.Resources``` holds the styles from that ResourceDictionary?

Comment: @ewerspej Oh my mistake yeah it is `../`, just had a typo in my answer.  But the problem is not htat it doesn't find the file, just not the styles. When I type a wrong path it shows a different error^^  
I did not declare any resources in `<Application.Resources>`. So I don't think I'd get a result there, right? It's only declared in the `<Window.Resources>`.